# WPF ComboBox validation error when binding to IEnumerable of Enum values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, enums

For the purpose of code reuse, I am attempting to bind a `ComboBox ItemsSource` to an enumerable of enum values defined in a viewmodel. (I am aware of the strategies for binding directly to the enum, but in order to achieve code reuse I need to bind to an enumerable.) On viewmodel construction, I set the selected item to the first value of the enumerable.  When the UI first launches, however, the combobox loads with validation error:

> Value '' could not be converted.

This error does not occur when I use the same XAML to bind to an enumerable of classes.  After I select an enum value, I get no more validation errors and the UI works as intended.  **How do I avoid this error and get the combobox to display the selected item on startup?**

The code details... I have a service implementing `IAcquire<T>` which returns an enumerable of enum values:

```
public interface IAcquire<T>
{
    IReactiveList<T> Items { get; }
}
```

My viewmodel inheritance looks something like this:

```
    class GranularitySelectionViewModel : ChartFilterSelectionBase<DataGranularity>
    {
        public GranularitySelectionViewModel([NotNull] IAcquire<DataGranularity> service) 
            : base(service, "Granularity")
        {}
    }


class ChartFilterSelectionBase<T> : SelectionViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IAcquire<T> _service;

    internal ChartFilterSelectionBase([NotNull] IAcquire<T> service, string label)
        :base(label)
    {
            foreach (var value in service.Items)
            {
                Items.Add(value);
            }
            SelectedItem = Items.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private readonly IReactiveList<T> _items = new ReactiveList<T>();

    public new IReactiveList<T> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    private T _selectedItem;

    public new T SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value); }
    }
}

public class SelectionBaseViewModel
{
    protected SelectionBaseViewModel([NotNull] string label )
    {
        if (label == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("label");
        _label = label;
    }

    private readonly string _label;

    public string Label
    {
        get { return _label; }
    }

    //Placeholder to be overridden in derived class.
    public object SelectedItem { get; set; }

    //Placeholder to be overridden in derived class.
    public IReactiveList<object> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

The XAML is as follows:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SelectionBaseViewModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Content="{Binding Label}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:" Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
        <ComboBox Margin="5,0,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```